# How to write rows with the file name in Column A to CSV files?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to generate CSV files from a set of records from Excel.

Column A is the file name and the rest of the columns are the data to write to the the file.

As of now, I am using `WriteLine`, but it doesn't work as expected:

[image: Example of input and output data]

As you can see, I don't get the expected output. How do I get the expected output?

```vb
Private Sub ommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    Path = "C:\Access Permissions\Users"
    Folder = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)
    
    If Folder = vbNullString Then
    
        '-------------Create Folder -----------------------
        MkDir ("C:\Access Permissions")
        MkDir ("C:\Access Permissions\Roles")
        MkDir ("C:\Access Permissions\Users")
    
    Else
        Set rngSource = Range("A4", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        rngSource.Copy Range("AA1")
        Range("AA:AA").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        Set rngUnique = Range("AA1", Range("AA" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set lr = Cells(rngSource.Rows.Count, rngSource.Column)
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        For Each cell In rngUnique
            n = Application.CountIf(rngSource, cell.Value)
            Set C = rngSource.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, after:=lr)
            Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Access Permissions\Users\" & cell.Value & "-Users.csv")
            For i = 1 To n
            
                oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 1).Value
                oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 2).Value
                oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 3).Value
                oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 4).Value
                
                oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 6).Value
                oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 7).Value
                 
                Set C = rngSource.FindNext(C)
            Next i
        
        Next cell
        
        rngUnique.ClearContents
        MsgBox "Individual Users.csv files got generated" & vbCrLf & "  " & vbCrLf & "Path - C:\Access Permissions\Groups "
    End If
End Sub
```

**Updated Image**:

[image: Updated Image]

Let me re-phrase my questions.

Updated Image Enclosed.

1. Using the Data Set [Updated Image point 1], It creates unique CSV files based on column A.
2. File got saved at the path given.
3. As of now the row data associated with each file name got written in the files but in a new line manner.
4. As expected, how the output can be written in Columns.[ Updated Image Point 4]
5. Given code is working without any error.
   5.1. I just need to click twice if the Path folder does not exist.
   5.2. at first click, it creates the Folder at the given path.
   5.3. at Second click it generates the unique files, with its records.

If you can please guide me on how the records can be written in columns [ Updated Image Point 4 ], expected output.

[Download File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15N0jWuUqrRhMtelk-2XTLB5RseduyUSI/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data does not contain any semicolons.

You are writing each field on a line by itself. Instead, join the fields on a single line:

```vb
oFile.WriteLine C.Offset(0, 1).Value & ";" & _
                C.Offset(0, 2).Value & ";" & _
                C.Offset(0, 3).Value & ";" & _
                C.Offset(0, 4).Value & ";" & _
                C.Offset(0, 6).Value & ";" & _
                C.Offset(0, 7).Value
```

There are other bugs in your example; it should not work as far as I can see. For example, you keep opening the same file with [CreateTextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method). You should only create a file once, not every time you write to it. According to the documentation, you should get an error on your second try, see [CreateTextFile method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createtextfile-method). The reason you don't get an error is probably because you never close the file. You should close the files you create.

I would use this approach instead:

```vb
' Collect the data for each file into a dictionary.
' The cells in the table must not contain semicolons.
Sub Doit()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastRowNum As Long, LastColNum  As Long
    Dim Lst As Variant, Hdr As Variant, Elem As Variant
    Dim Idx As Long, Idx2 As Long
    Dim Dct As Object
    Dim HdrTxt, Txt As String, Sep As String
    Dim Filename As String
    
    Set Sht = ActiveSheet
    
    ' Get the last row in column 1
    Set Rng = Sht.Cells(Sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
    LastRowNum = Rng.Row
    
    ' Get the last column in row 3
    Set Rng = Sht.Cells(3, Sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
    LastColNum = Rng.Column
    
    ' Get the headers in row 3
    Set Rng = Sht.Range(Sht.Cells(3, 1), Sht.Cells(3, LastColNum))
    Hdr = Rng
    
    ' Create a semicolon seprated line for the headers
    HdrTxt = ""
    Sep = ""
    For Idx = LBound(Hdr, 2) To UBound(Hdr, 2)
        HdrTxt = HdrTxt & Sep & Hdr(1, Idx)
        Sep = ";"
    Next Idx
    HdrTxt = HdrTxt & vbNewLine
    
    ' Get the data from row 4 and down
    Set Rng = Sht.Range(Sht.Cells(4, 1), Sht.Cells(LastRowNum, LastColNum))
    Lst = Rng
    
    ' Store the data for each file in a dicitonary
    Set Dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Idx = LBound(Lst) To UBound(Lst)
        Filename = Lst(Idx, 1)
        ' Create a semicolon seprated line
        Txt = ""
        Sep = ""
        For Idx2 = LBound(Lst, 2) To UBound(Lst, 2)
            Txt = Txt & Sep & Lst(Idx, Idx2)
            Sep = ";"
        Next Idx2
        Txt = Txt & vbNewLine
        ' Add the line to the dictionary
        If Dct.Exists(Filename) Then
            Dct(Filename) = Dct(Filename) & Txt
        Else
            Dct(Filename) = HdrTxt & Txt
        End If
    Next Idx
    
    ' Output data for each file to the immdiate window
    For Each Elem In Dct
        ' Change this to open the file and write the contents
        Debug.Print "---- Filename: " & Elem
        Debug.Print Dct(Elem)
    Next Elem
End Sub
```

The example makes sure you only create the files once:

Change the last loop *For Each Elem In Dct* that prints the data to the immediate window, to create a file instead. Use the [Write method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/write-method) instead of the WriteLine method, as the data already contains the line-breaks. And remember to [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/close-method-textstream-object) the files.

Comment: Why store the range in a variant instead of looping through the cells on the spreadsheet? Does this have a better performance?

Comment: When you assign a *Variant* to a *Range* (directly without using *Set*), the data in the range is converted into an Array (provided the range contains more than one cell). Limiting the number of times you refer to excel objects (COM Objects), will in most cases improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:B" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2010
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".txt": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
    MyPath = "C:\Users\ryans\OneDrive\Desktop\"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create folder for the new files
    foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                ChDir MyPath
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
                foldername & cell.Value & ".txt", _
                FileFormat:=xlTextMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False

        
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the expert solutions and suggestions, I have provided a link to my file and updated the image for expected output.
the file does not have any errors.Thanks

Comment: So, did my suggestion work for you or not? I'm a tad bit confused.

Comment: Thank you sir, your solution worked with error files got generated under Time stamp, folder & log on the main data sheet. All the error files got some ASCII code.

Comment: I still don't know what you are talking about, but it kind of sounds like you're very, very close to where you want to be. I'll let you figure out the last 1%. It will be a good learning exercise for you.

Comment: Firstly I am very new to vba ,I tried your code, but it’s picking only two columns, and it’s a txt files. It has to be CVS file. And as per the screen shot the data set consist of multiple columns, but while creating the CVS file it use only few columns from the dada set. As a result it should not include role column as a generated files.

Comment: Text and CSV are pretty much the same thing. Just change ".txt" to ".csv". That's it.

Comment: Also, change "A1:B" to whatever you want. You can do "A1:Z". You can make the columns dynamic too. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion, I made some small changes & it’s working and giving the output in CVS format. 
One question let’s say we have set a range from A1 to E so while generating the CVS file it’s giving me columns A to E. How I can set a range for multiple columns as A1:E and G:I , so when the output is generated it will given me the columns from A to E then G to I . Please advice, many thanks sir

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question for that.